# How to handle end of loading event?

Tags: ember.js, promise, loading

I have the following test application, implementing the [loading](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_loading) event:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

function delayedPromise(delay, value) {
    delay = delay || 3000;
    value = value || { msg: 'Delayed promise has been fulfilled' };
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
        Ember.run.later(function() {
            console.info('Delayed promise has been fulfilled');
            resolve(value);
        }, delay);
    });
    return promise;
}

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    return delayedPromise();
  },

  actions: {

    loading : function() {
      $.blockUI();
    },

  }
});
```

Which is working as expected: the UI is blocked by the `loading` event.

How can I unblock the UI (`$.unblockUI()`)? Is there a `loadingFinished` (or similar) action that I can implement whenever all models have finished resolving?

Working jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/qatago/4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example of [Legacy Loading Route](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_legacy-code-loadingroute-code) you could:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    return delayedPromise();
  },

  actions: {

    loading : function() {
      $.blockUI();
      this.router.one('didTransition', $, 'unblockUI');
    },

  }
});
```

Comment: It is also possible to handle the [didTransition](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition) event